# Swift 2.2 AVPlayer error handling

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, swift2, avplayer

I'm trying to catch an error on AVPlayer (Swift 2.2) when streaming url is server down with no success.

I did add status and rate observers but their respond is not the expected. It states that player status is ready to play.

```
playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: streaminglink)!)
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: .New, context: nil)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: .New, context: nil)
player.rate = 1.0
player.play()
```

Any hints will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i removed the rate observer and instead of status observer on player, i applied it in playerItem

```
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
```

Now, i get when my streaming is online, or server is currently down.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle network changes with an observer for AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification : [AVPlayer : How to handle network interruptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438095/avplayer-how-to-handle-network-interruptions)

Comment: Thanks for your proposal and prompt response. I'll give it a try.