# How to handle timeout request failed in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to load remote video URL in AVPlayer.

If there is a poor Internet connection, I want to show an alert on timeout request failed.

Comment: Use `URLRequest` with `URLSession` if that's so important.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should add an observer for the status. Check this link about [AVPlayer Network Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438095/avplayer-how-to-handle-network-interruptions). The details of AVPlayer you can find on official documentation [AVPlayer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer).

[image]